# Удалил данные из mysql, теперь новые данные в базу не приходят и ошибка 500, что это значит и как я могу решить проблему?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

На клиенте react, на бэкенде express.js. связь с mySql через sequilize. Всё работало хорошо пока я не удалил из базы все данные вот так:

- в index.js:

```
async function start() {
  try {
    // sequelize.sync() может принимать аргументом {force: true} и именно это позволило мне 
    // удалить данные из базы, ниже дописал как
    await sequelize.sync({force: true});
    app.listen(PORT);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

далее модель данных

- model.js:

```
const deviceData = sequelize.define("Device", {
  // здесь были поля со значениями, по сути данные которые передавались сюда через клиента,
 // и я их удалил просто вырезав
});
```

затем я добавил новые поля и в await sequelize.sync() убрал {force: true}

Но при первом же onSubmit получил POST http://localhost:3000/api/router 500 (Internal Server Error)

Пробовал базу переустанавливать, но не помогло, кстати новые поля в базе отображаются

Comment: может он в лог еще что-то пишет подробней

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста лог на скриншоте: на одном стэк показан, на другом  обработчик, где ошибка указывает на метод fetch:  https://pastenow.ru/9U4H7    https://pastenow.ru/9U4GK

Comment: `500` -- ошибка на сервере; смотрите его логи

Comment: ох, а как! я совсем первый раз это делаю, где это нужно смотреть и какой порядок действий?

Comment: 1) Глянул в репозиторий -- всё красиво. Запускать не пробовал, среды рядом нету. Я вообще nodejs серверный мало трогал 2) Для логов самое место -- консоль где express запускается, может так какой-то стек проскочит при запросе. 3) Может ошибка где-то ловится и игнорируется (типа `catch(e){}`); понавтыкать `console.log` на сервере 4) От переинсталляции базы данные могли не пропасть; надо понять где они хранятся

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать в этом направлении, затем отпишусь